# How to restore the original row order with JTable's row sorter?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I've enabled sorting in JTable with setAutoCreateRowSorter method. Mouse clicks on the column headers will switch between ascending and descending order, but I would like to switch it between ascending, descending and the original (unsorted) row order. Any hints how to achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The mapping of a mouse click to changing the sort state is implemented in BasicTableHeaderUI and happens exclusively via the RowSorter's toggleSortOrder(columnIndex). It's default behaviour is to switch

UNSORTED --> ASCENDING --> DESCENDING --> ASCENDING --

that is, no way back into the UNSORTED. If the requirement is to simply widen the circle into:

UNSORTED --> ASCENDING --> DESCENDING -- UNSORTED --> ASCENDING --

the way to go is to subclass TableRowSorter and override its toggleSortOrder accordingly

```
    /** 
     * @inherited <p>
     */
    @Override
    public void toggleSortOrder(int column) {
        List<? extends SortKey> sortKeys = getSortKeys();
        if (sortKeys.size() > 0) {
            if (sortKeys.get(0).getSortOrder() == SortOrder.DESCENDING) {
                setSortKeys(null);
                return;
            }
        }
        super.toggleSortOrder(column);
    }
```

Note: this is a bit simplified as it doesn't account for n-ary sorted columns, see SwingX DefaultSortController for a full version. Or use SwingX to start with, its JXTable has api to configure the sorting cycle like

```
 table.setSortOrderCycle(ASCENDING, DESCENDING, UNSORTED);
```

Cheers
Jeanette

Comment: Be aware that setting the row sorter yourself means you don't have to call setAutoCreateRowSorter() any more. If you still call it, it will overwrite the RowSorter you added.

Answer (score 6):

This code implements cycle ASCENDING->DESCENDING->UNSORTED->... without overriding TableRowSorter:

```
TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter(getModel());
setRowSorter(sorter);
// Remove default sort MouseListener
for (MouseListener mouseListener : getTableHeader().getMouseListeners()) {
    if (mouseListener instanceof javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI.MouseInputHandler) {
        getTableHeader().removeMouseListener(mouseListener);
    }
}
// Add MouseListener for onClick event
getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    private SortOrder currentOrder = SortOrder.UNSORTED;

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int column = getTableHeader().columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        RowSorter sorter = getRowSorter();
        List sortKeys = new ArrayList();
        switch (currentOrder) {
            case UNSORTED:
                sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(column, currentOrder = SortOrder.ASCENDING));
                break;
            case ASCENDING:
                sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(column, currentOrder = SortOrder.DESCENDING));
                break;
            case DESCENDING:
                sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(column, currentOrder = SortOrder.UNSORTED));
                break;
        }
        sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the [`DefaultRowSorter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html): "An empty `sortKeys` list indicates that the view should [be] unsorted, the same as the model."

```
RowSorter rs = table.getRowSorter();
rs.setSortKeys(null);
```

Addendum: Note that "`null` is a shorthand for specifying an empty list" in [`setSortKeys()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html#setSortKeys%28java.util.List%29).

Answer (score 4):

Kornell's answer is working great for me (thanks!)

I made these changes which others may find helpful:

1. Convert column from view to model coordinates.  This is a bug in the original.
2. Omit removing the other mouse listeners, because doing this disables column dragging and resizing.
3. Filter out anything but left clicks
4. Whenever column changes, reinitialize sort order.  User experience is significantly more intuitive this way, as you can successively click different columns and get ascending order each time.

   ```
   TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter(getModel());
   setRowSorter(sorter);
   getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
       private SortOrder   currentOrder    = SortOrder.UNSORTED;
       private int         lastCol         = -1;

       @Override
       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
           int column = getTableHeader().columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
           column = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
           if (column != lastCol) {
               currentOrder = SortOrder.UNSORTED;
               lastCol = column;
           }
           RowSorter<?> sorter = getRowSorter();
           List<SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<SortKey>();
           if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
               switch (currentOrder) {
                   case UNSORTED:
                       sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(column, currentOrder = SortOrder.ASCENDING));
                   break;
                   case ASCENDING:
                       sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(column, currentOrder = SortOrder.DESCENDING));
                   break;
                   case DESCENDING:
                       sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(column, currentOrder = SortOrder.UNSORTED));
                   break;
               }
               sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
           }
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Since the built-in sorting mechanism gives you ascending or descending order only, you could return to the original state if you provide an external reload-JButton, somewhere near your JTable, that just sets the same model back to what you had as you displayed the Table the first time, before any sorting activity took place.

Answer (score -1):

If you looking for UI way of doing it - shift-click on column header will do it. This is built-in JTable functionality

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. Perhaps it's platform dependant, I'm using Linux.

Comment: I'm sorry. It only works with JXTable available from SwingX library. Pure JTable does not have this functionality. But I would imagine that it can be achieved by removing RowSorter - it will turn sorting off effectively bringing back your original sort order

Comment: JXTable (strictly speaking JXTableHeader) no longer supports the reset-all-sorts - was dropped in version 1.6 when switching target jdk6.